# How can I create a working eclipse plug-in update site for a plug-in that works in debug mode?

Tags: eclipse

I created a working eclipse plug-in with some kind help from stackoverflow.  By "working", I mean that it works correctly when I start an eclipse application as "Overview -> Testing -> Launch an eclipse application".  I.e., I am running eclipse in "Plug-in development" perspective, I have an eclipse plug-in coded up, and I can run it under a separate "child" eclipse from the "Plug-in development" eclipse instance.

I then carefully followed the instructions in "Create a feature".."Create an update site".."Install and uninstall a feature" process under "Welcome -> Tutorials -> Create an eclipse plugin."

I was then able to install the resulting feature without complaint into eclipse.  However, when I stop and restart eclipse, the feature is completely broken; it does not work at all the way it worked during plug-in development.

The feature adds a menu item to the Team pop-up menu, and starts a new editor when that menu item is selected.  In the non-working installed version, the menu item is not present, nowhere to be found.

I will include my project's plugin.xml, build.properties, and MANIFEST.MF below.

Any help on how to debug install problems would be greatly appreciated.  Classpath issue?  Any other landmines that are easy for the unwary to step on?

plugin.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<?eclipse version="3.4"?>
<plugin>
   <extension point="org.eclipse.ui.popupMenus">

      <objectContribution
            objectClass="org.eclipse.core.resources.IFile"
            id="com.gregfjohnson.hg_version_view.contribution1">

         <action
               label="Version View"
               class="com.gregfjohnson.hg_version_view.popup.actions.NewAction"            
               menubarPath="team.main/group4"
               enablesFor="1"
               id="com.gregfjohnson.hg_version_view.newAction">
         </action>

      </objectContribution>

   </extension>

</plugin>
```

build.properties:

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               META-INF/,\
```

MANIFEST.MF:

```
Manifest-Version: 1.0
Bundle-ManifestVersion: 2
Bundle-Name: Hg_version_view
Bundle-SymbolicName: com.gregfjohnson.hg_version_view; singleton:=true
Bundle-Version: 1.0.0.qualifier
Bundle-Activator: com.gregfjohnson.hg_version_view.Activator
Bundle-Vendor: GREGFJOHNSON
Require-Bundle: org.eclipse.ui,
 org.eclipse.core.runtime,
 org.eclipse.core.resources,
 org.eclipse.core.filesystem;bundle-version="1.3.100",
 org.eclipse.ui.ide;bundle-version="3.7.0"
Bundle-RequiredExecutionEnvironment: JavaSE-1.6
Bundle-ActivationPolicy: lazy
```

Answer (score 0):

Your bin.includes should have a '.' in it as well.  Is that just a typo?

```
source.. = src/
output.. = bin/
bin.includes = plugin.xml,\
               .,\
               META-INF/
```

Also, what kind of projects or files are you looking at?  Your objectContribution might need to be marked as adaptable.

Comment: Thanks a million, Paul!  I will check those two issues.

Comment: I have one project I was able to create an update site for before I inadvertantly changed something (checked box in the eclipse gui somewhere, who knows?).

Two differences between the happy deployed plug-in and the broken one:

in artifacts.xml, the good one has a section

<artifact classifier='osgi.bundle' ... </artifact> which is missing from the broken one.

And, the good features.xml has a plugin section
<plugin
id="com.example.helloworld"
download-size="0"
install-size="0"
version="1.0.0.201207081138"
unpack="false"/>

that is missing from the features.xml file for the broken one.